# How to access page controls inside a static web method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, pagemethods

I have called a Code behind method using jQuery using a static `WebMethod` method.

That web method call was success but when tried to access a text box control it is giving error. An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

```
[WebMethod]    
public static Savedata()
 {
     //code to insert data to DB

     //after inserting data successfully i need to change the text box text like following.        
      txtStatus.Text="Data Received";   
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned by @Tim Schmelter This doesn't answer this question because **you can't access page's controls from a webmethod**.

Please go through 
[asp.net access a control from static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684974/asp-net-access-a-control-from-static-function)

The whole point of [WebMethod]s is that they don't run the ASP.Net page lifecycle. This way, they're fast and parallelizable.
Your controls don't exist.

your question is duplicate of [How to get controls in static web method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967763/how-to-get-controls-in-static-method)

Comment: here i get Null value..:(

Comment: This doesn't answer this question because you can't access page's controls from a webmethod. So maybe it's helpful for future readers because of the title but it's the wrong answer for this issue.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: you are right.

Comment: Then why it is up-voted ?

Comment: **Wrong! Wrong! Wrong!** You can never modify controls' state in service (*web method*) call.

Answer (score 6):

**The accepted answer is wrong for web methods.**

As [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) mentioned correctly in a comment:

> you can't access page's controls from a webmethod

That is true since web methods don't carry the page state. It isn't a full postback. Instead just the session cookie travels with the request. You have to do a full page postback to get or set the control values.