# How to access ImageButton control from another class?

Tags: c#, webforms

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function ShowCurrentTime(name) {
         PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(name, OnSuccess);
         }
         function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
          alert(response);
         }
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="IMGBTN001" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/ico/labaniat.png"
class="img-responsive em-img-lazy" OnClientClick="ShowCurrentTime('01')" />

<asp:Image class="img-responsive retina-img em-img-lazy" ID="IMGMostViewed" runat="server"ImageUrl="Images/Banner/block1_banner.jpg" />
```

Code Behind C#

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    //string x = IMGMostViewed.ImageUrl;
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

I want to access the Image from another class.

How can I access the IMGMostViewed this GetCurrentTime class?

i used this code, but get "page.FindControl("IMGMostViewed")" return null

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        Image IMGMostViewed = (Image)page.FindControl("IMGMostViewed");
        string x = IMGMostViewed.ImageUrl;
    }
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoreticaly you can cast the CurrentHandler to your type of page and then access your button:

```
var currentHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as T;
currentHandler.IMGBTN001.ImageUrl = "abc";
```

The beter way would be to access your button on clientside in your success function.

```
     function ShowCurrentTime(name) {
      PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(name, OnSuccess);
     }
     function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
      //Access here your button and modify it
     }
```

Here you also will find a related Answer:
[How to access page controls inside a static web method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514188/how-to-acess-page-controls-inside-a-static-method-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is ' T '  in HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as T;?

Comment: T should represent your page, then you have an instance of your page and you are able to access your imagebutton :)

Comment: I use this but get null reference

Comment: I added a link, have a look at this, if it won't help post your code again
(page markup; page codebehind, page webmethod javascript)

Comment: @Cyril Iselin  HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler return null reference ?