# Accessing master page control from WebMthod

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, master-pages, webmethod

I have been struggling with accessing a control in master page from a web method (or any static method for that matter).

I have a bootstrap-styled drop down in master page that list user's favorites. Items in this drop down are populated using a repeater that reads list of favorites for current user from DB and populates the drop down.

On the main page that uses this master page there are a number of reports with an "Add to favorites" button. To do this client side, I added an onclick event to button, it calls a javascript function that calls a web method to store this info (User ID, URL) in database. This part is fine. The problem is that then I need to update the dropdown (rebind the repeater).

Here is what I have and what I have tried:

In master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="EA.SiteMaster" %>
....
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" />
....
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFavorites" OnItemDataBound="rptFavorites_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbFavLink"  /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> 
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

in Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EA._Default" %>
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="Site.master" %>
....
function addFavorite(sURL, sFriendlyName) {
    // I added this to get the routing working properly
    var path = PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx';

    PageMethods.set_path(path);
    PageMethods.AddUserFavorite(sURL, sFriendlyName, onSucceeded, onFailed);
}
function onSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
    alert(result);
}
function onFailed(result, userContext, methodName) {
    alert(result);
}
....
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btnMPP" onclick="addFavorite('http://blahblah.com/IV/SomeReport.html','Some Report')" ><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

in Default.aspx.cs:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AddUserFavorite(string sURL, string sFriendlyName)
{
    string sMsg = string.Empty;
    string sUserID = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
    Favorites oFavorite = new Favorites();
    oFavorite.FavoritesURL = sURL;
    oFavorite.FavoritesFriendlyName = sFriendlyName;
    oFavorite.UserID = sUserID;

    int iRet = Favorites.AddFavrites(oFavorite);

    if (-1 == iRet)
        sMsg = "Failed to add to favorites list";
    else
    {
        sMsg = "\"" + sFriendlyName + "\" (" + sURL + ") was added to your favorites list";
        UpdateMaster();
    }
    return sMsg;
}

private static void UpdateMaster()
{
    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    MasterPage mp = page.Master; <--- Always null

    Repeater rptFavorites = mp.FindControl("rptFavorites") as Repeater;

    if (rptFavorites != null)
    {
        // rebind repeater here
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this is greatly appreciated. Of course, I can change the "Add to Favorites" to an ASP LinkButton and no issues, but just need to know how this approach can be done; if it can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need this code to access your repeater.

```
Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
MasterPage mp = page.Master; <--- Always null
```

You just need to tell it to look for it in the MasterPage.
Try it this way.

```
(Repeater) rpt = (Repeater) Master.FindControl("rptFavorites");
```

Comment: Won't work. That was my very first attempt. Can't access controls from static method. If you are calling a method that is defined in a user class, you can create an instance of the class from Web Method and then call the function; but I am not using a class.

Comment: Doing more research on this, I just found out that you can't. As this discussion has. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514188/how-to-access-page-controls-inside-a-static-web-method I just wish I could be more helpful.