# getting null value when getting the datatable value to the textbox in static web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webmethod

when textbox getting the data through datatable object in static method at that time it shows the null value (i.e. showing error : object reference not set to an instance of the object). But when I am doing the debug mode at that time it shows the data in the datatable, so from that I am confusing that how in textbox it getting the null value.

Here is my code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void GetCnorGSTNo(string Param1)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        TextBox cnorGST = (TextBox)page.FindControl("txtbx_cnortin");

        DataAccess clsObjDataAccess = new DataAccess();
        string qrySelCnorGtinNo = "select TinNo1 from CnorMaster where CnorName = '" + Param1 + "'";
        DataTable dtqrySelCnorGtinNo = new DataTable();
        dtqrySelCnorGtinNo = clsObjDataAccess.GetDataTable(qrySelCnorGtinNo);
        if (dtqrySelCnorGtinNo.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            cnorGST.Text = dtqrySelCnorGtinNo.Rows[0]["TinNo1"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

When I am doing in debug mode

```
"dtqrySelCnorGtinNo.Rows[0]["TinNo1"].ToString();"
```

this line shows the data

but when this data is giving to the textbox i.e. `cnorGST.Text` at that time it showing an error i.e. object reference not set to an instance of the object.

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thank You.

Comment: A webmethod runs outside of the context of a page's lifecycle, so the controls don't exist on the server. You cannot access them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514188/how-to-access-page-controls-inside-a-static-web-method

Comment: is there any thing that I can access the control. Because whatever the value is coming in the datatable that value I want to show the textbox. Then how can I do this?

Comment: You can access the database in the webmethod, just return the value you want to show in the textbox. Then assign this text via javascript from clientside.

Answer (score 1):

A webmethod runs outside of the context of a page's lifecycle, so the controls don't exist on the server. [You cannot access them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514188/how-to-access-page-controls-inside-a-static-web-method).

But you are calling this webemethod from a clientside method. There you can assign the text. So get the value from the database in the webmethod and return it:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCnorGSTNo(string Param1)
{
    DataAccess clsObjDataAccess = new DataAccess();
    string qrySelCnorGtinNo = "select TinNo1 from CnorMaster where CnorName = '" + Param1 + "'";
    return clsObjDataAccess.GetDataTable(qrySelCnorGtinNo).AsEnumerable()
       .ElementAtOrDefault(0)?.Field<string>("TinNo1");
}
```

The javascript method that calls this webmethod assigns the returned text to `txtbx_cnortin.Value`.

> Sir, can you give me this parameterized queries demo. I'm using sqlserver2005

Sure

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCnorGSTNo(string cnorName)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection-string here"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select TinNo1 from CnorMaster where CnorName = @CnorName", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CnorName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cnorName;
        con.Open();
        object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return val == DBNull.Value ? "" : (string)val;
    }
}
```

Since i don't know the db-type of the `TinNo1`-column you might have to change the `(string)val`.

Comment: @karan: note that you should use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation. Otherwise you are (very) prone to sql-injection attacks.

Comment: Sir, can you give me this parameterized queries demo.

Comment: sqlserver2005, 2008r2

Comment: Sir, you mean to say that I want to do parameterized queries like store procedure.....right?

Comment: how can I select the multiple field in parameterized query. for ex if I want to do the query like "select TinNo1, TinNo2 from CnorMaster where CnorName = @CnorName" then how can I return the value in json? @Tim Schmelter