# How to set Label Text in .aspx markup using a static class in application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the static class within a solution,
namespace WebApplication1

```
{
    public static class LabelValues
    {
        public static string GetLabelValue(string str)
        {
            Return "Hello" + str; //There's a complicated logic for this
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want set Label text using below code. but its not working

```
<asp:Label ID="_label1" runat="server" Text="<%# LabelValues.GetLabelValue("_label1") %>" >
```

I want to call static class from Text attribute of label control to set values for labels.

Comment: Please include the error message you get.

Comment: The name "LabelValues" does not exist in current context.

Comment: Have you added the namespace that LabelValues exists in to the ASPX page?

Comment: Write out the complete namespace:  `WebApplication1.LabelValues.GetLabelValue("_label1")`

Comment: I think you have to take a look here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967763/how-to-get-controls-in-static-web-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967763/how-to-get-controls-in-static-web-method) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133194/access-asp-net-control-from-static-webmethod-js-ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133194/access-asp-net-control-from-static-webmethod-js-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

As VDWWD has mentioned you can write out the complete namespace. Also for data binding syntax I believe you need to wrap it in single quotes.

```
<asp:Label ID="_label1" runat="server" Text='<%# WebApplication1.LabelValues.GetLabelValue("_label1") %>' >
```

As seen here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bda9bbfx(v=vs.100)