# call server side method on jquery price slider event which change the datasource of repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, controls, webmethod

I am trying to filter results based on user price range selection . so I choose the jquery slider for showing range of price. and I have decided to call web method using jquery `ajax` on slider `stop event` .

everything is fine at this stage .here is code for my web method which filter the records basis on min and max range passed by jquery `ajax` call

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void FilterByPrice(double min,double max)
    {
        List<BALHotelList> searchresult =(List<BALHotelList>) HttpContext.Current.Session["searchresult"];
        searchresult = searchresult.Where(t => (double)t.totalPrice >= min && (double)t.totalPrice <= max).ToList();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["searchresult"] = searchresult;        
        SearchResult s = new SearchResult();
        s.Paging();
    }
```

Now problem is with `Paging` method which is used to set the `datasource` of  repeater control . Paging method as follow:

```
 protected  void Paging()
    {
        List<BALHotelList> searchresult = (List<BALHotelList>)Session["searchresult"];
        PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
        objPds.DataSource = searchresult;
        objPds.AllowPaging = true;
        objPds.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPageNo.SelectedValue);

        objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

        lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of "
           + objPds.PageCount.ToString();

        // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
        cmdPrev.Enabled = !objPds.IsFirstPage;
        cmdNext.Enabled = !objPds.IsLastPage;

        rptHotels.DataSource = objPds;
        rptHotels.DataBind();
    }
```

when this method is called its through error that **object reference not set** . I understand that this time page controls can not be accessed. as I read some answers which are deny completely this [issue regarding access page control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914336/issue-regarding-access-page-control-from-static-method-asp-net-4-0)

Now I want to know what approach should I use to complete my task which is

**use jquery price slider to filter the records?**

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change your **WebMehtod** signature to return the filtered records and them use jQuery to show them. This can be acomplished through the [DataTables jQuery plug-in](http://datatables.net/), which is an open source tool for building feature rich html tables.

[This javascript example code](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) shows how to set up and fill a DataTable using jQuery.