# Access to GridView values from WebMethod Asp.Net C#

Tags: jquery, webmethod, aspxgridview

I using jquery ajax to send data to code behind....

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'Epad.aspx/generateReport',
data: "{'exportOptions':" + JSON.stringify( exportOptions ) + "}",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json',
async: true,
```

cache: false,
   });

I calling WebMethod....

```
public static  void generateReport(dataReportEpad[] exportOptions) {....}
```

In the WebMethod I need access to C# Gridview and some TextBox that are inside the Gridview....

How can I do it?

Comment: Wrong question. I think you are confusing the concepts. Even if you could access GridView nothing will happened on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't access controls in WebMethods.

I found this link where this same question was already posted:

[Accessing ASP control from webmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178938/accessing-asp-control-from-webmethod)

Comment: Thanks.. Now I understand that I can't access to Controls from WebMethod... But Are there another solution to pass values to code behind and are able to access to the Controls...?

Comment: For asp.net the simplest way is using an update panel. You can find additional help here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/